# Is it okay to move the beer while its fermenting?

Tags: fermentation

I just started my very first batch of beer, so I am a big noobie. Earlier today I checked the temperature of the keg and it seemed a little high (74F) so I decided to try moving it somewhere else. Afterwards though I was wondering to myself if its okay to move beer while its fermenting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's generally ok to move the beer. I do it often if the room temperature changes and I'm not using my fridge for temperature control.

During the first 24h of the ferment it's almost advantageous to move the beer, since any sloshing will serve to aerate the wort a little, and that's good for the yeast.

At the end of fermentation, be a little more careful if you're using plastic, since moving the beer can cause the plastic carboys/pails to flex and push CO2 out and later suck air back in. You can hear the airlock gurgle as the gas flows back and forth. It's nothing significant to worry about, (unless you start playing the bucket like an accordion), but worth knowing about all the same. You want to minimize contact with air once fermentation has started to slow.

PS: Congrats! First batch. Tasting your first beer can be a lot like your first kiss. You remember every little nuance - the appearance, aroma, taste, the bite on the tongue... :D

Comment: I usually remove the airlock before moving my beer to avoid it sucking the fluid in. Not a big deal, no, but I dislike it all the same. After the beer is settled I'll resanitize and install the airlock again.

Comment: Here's a tip: when the airlock is not filled past the "max fill" line, it's impossible for it to suck the fluid back in. It will then only suck in air.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks mdma :). It was within the first 24 hours btw.

Answer (score 5):

It's fine to move the beer while fermenting, but do your best to minimize sloshing which could introduce oxygen and eventually oxidise the beer.

Also, use caution when moving full glass carboys. There have been [reported](http://brewing.lustreking.com/articles/brokencarboys.html) incidents of the neck snapping and causing injury.

Comment: Good point about the glass carboys. I don't use them an often forget that others do!

Comment: I second this!!  I am now not too proud to use my brew hauler.....after lacerations to both hands, feet, and stomach.